# Additive Blending and Gamma Correction

Tags: graphics-programming, blending, alpha-blending, srgb

Should one do additive blending (aka lightmapping) in linear space?

I tried doing it in linear space, and it became, well, linear and bland, losing that cool HDR-style bloomy effect. Is there some standard way to do additive blending in linear RGB, or additive blending is now an obsolete gamma space hack and people should forget about it?

Comment: The standard way to do additive blending in linear RGB is to just add two numbers — nothing fancy. If doing that isn't giving you the effect you like, you can use a different blending function. Try showing us an example of the output you have now, and how it differs from the output you want, and we can suggest ways to get closer to your desired effect.

Comment: Here I applied a light to a background in gamma and in linear space: https://imgur.com/M8Lmmje

Comment: If you like the gamma space effect better, then it sounds like you already have a solution. What do you need from us?

Comment: Just curious what is the industry standard to apply such lightmaps today, when everything is done in linear space.

Comment: `(a^gamma+b^gamma)^(1/gamma)` is not equal to `(a+b)^(1/gamma)`

Comment: What we call "lightmaps" are generally applied in a different way. Here we render just the lighting component from each light, as though it were shining on a surface with a pure white albedo. Multiple lights are combined additively. Then when we render the material surfaces, we multiply the albedo with the accumulated lighting in the lightmap (so a true black albedo yields black output, absorbing incident light, rather than having light added on top of it). It sounds like you're using the term in a different way?

Comment: So lightmaps are multiplicative blending (src_color*dst_color)? That is interesting, because before that I used multiplicative blending for sharp lights, but it was still a bit bland, so additive blending was seems like the way to go, but it fails in linear space.

Comment: It sounds like what you might want to ask is "How do I add lighting to my scene"

Comment: Use a simple 2x modulate - (texture * lightmaps * 2) - to achieve the effect of brighter lights making the texture brighter, which seems to be what you want.

Comment: @MaximusMinimus if you feel this solves the problem, please consider posting it as an answer that can be voted on and accepted if it works for the asker. :)

Comment: @DMGregory - probably more appropriate for the hypothetical '*It sounds like what you might want to ask is "How do I add lighting to my scene"*' question.

Comment: @Maximus-Minimus I'm trying to make sense of the additive blending in linear space, and example usage. I'm a bit reserved about using custom blending modes, not supported by glBlendFunc in case I will add support for OpenGL rendering. I did your modulate trick, but it was still a bit bland, compared to gamma-additive or blending in CIE XYZ. Multiplying the added light by 2 indeed made it brighter in linear space at the expense of background, which is now completely indiscernible:  https://i.imgur.com/FTUgjxR.png

Comment: @SmugLispWeenie - a 2x modulate blend is just glBlendFunc (GL_DST_COLOR, GL_SRC_COLOR); ie. (d * s + s * d), or (2 * s * d); fully supported in GL1.1.  Nonetheless, if it doesn't get you the result you're looking for, point taken.

Comment: Is it possible to replace that 2 by some custom value in glBlendFunc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to reproduce the type of additive blending you'd see in a photo editing app like Photoshop, you probably want to have both the source and the destination in a gamma-corrected color space such as sRGB. If you want to reproduce how light actually works, you should leave your colors in linear RGB.

When photo editing apps first implemented blend modes, they were done in a gamma-corrected color space. Doing an add of 2 colors in such a space (especially in 8-bits per channel) would cause a lot of clipping of colors. Because of this, there were blend modes that achieved some of the desired light-like effects in the gamma-corrected space. For example, the "screen" blend mode in gamma-corrected space looks a lot like an "add" blend mode in linear space.

Fast-forward 20 years and these apps started adding linear RGB as an option for editing and suddenly all the blend modes look "weird" (at least to users who had been doing gamma-corrected blending for the last 20 years). So some applications do a gamma correction before doing blending, and then convert the result back to linear afterwards. So if that's working for you, it's an absolutely fine way to do it. You wouldn't be the first!

See for example, [this book](https://flylib.com/books/en/2.104.1/battle_of_the_color_spaces.html):

> Artists have dealt with the problems of working directly in video space [i.e. gamma-corrected space] for years without even knowing. A perfect example is the Screen transfer mode, which is additive in nature but whose calculations are clearly convoluted when compared with the pure Add transfer mode. Screen uses a multiply-toward-white function with the advantage of avoiding the clipping associated with Add. But Add's reputation comes from its application in bright video-space images. Screen was invented only to help people be productive when working in video space, without overbrights; Screen darkens overbrights (Figures 11.11a, b, and c). Real light doesn't Screen, it Adds. Add is the new Screen, Multiply is the new Hard Light, and many other Blending modes become evident as mere kludges in linear floating point

Comment: Both GIMP and Photoshop still have gamma-space as the default mode, so artists need to be careful. But gamma space has a nice property of somewhat matching human perceptual gamma curve, which is dynamic, adjusting to environment brightness. Meaning artists don't have to do pow(x,2.2) each time. That appears to be the single biggest reason graphics editors still operate in gamma space.